# Using R plotly to produce a windrose chart

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I am aiming to produce a Wind Rose chart using `plotly` that plots a country's (`SG`) rating for 5 variables (`X1, X2, X3, X4, X5`).

**Reproducible Code**

```
library(plotly) # viz
library(tidyr)  # data munge
library(dplyr)  # data munge

# list of countries
Countries <- c("SG", "UK", "CAD", "USA", "AU")

# data 
set.seed(1)
data.frame(replicate(5, sample(0:10, 5, rep=TRUE))) %>%
    cbind(Countries) %>%
    gather(key = Variable
           , value = value
           , -Countries) ->
    df

# single country
SG <- df[df$Countries %in% c("SG"),]

# plot
plot_ly(SG
        , r = value         #radial
        , t = Variable      #angular coordinates
        , color = Variable
        , type = "area") %>%
    layout(radialaxis = list(ticksuffix = "pts")
           , orientation = 270
           , autosize = T
           , width = 500
           , height = 500
           , margin = list(l = 100
                           , r = 50
                           , b = 100
                           , t = 50
                           , pad = 0
                           , autoexpand=FALSE)) %>%
    config(displayModeBar = F, showLink = F) ->
    p
p
```

**The Issue**

Currently I get a blank canvas (see screenshot):
[image]

**UPDATE**

A further point to note per @MLavoie's comment, is that the plot is not a blank canvas when you plot `df` (see screenshot 2 below). However, it doesn't seem to reflect the input data. Eg. variable X1 in the plot has a value of 8 whereas the data has a value of `sum(df[df$Variable == "X1", "value"])` = 23.

[image]

Comment: did you notice that if you use df instead of SG, your code is working?

Comment: I did. But I wouldn't say "working". It plots something, but it doesn't seem to be correct. I'll update the question to explain why.